# Parse sqlite Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a question pertaining to Parse with use within Swift 2... Apparently when I attempt to run this app with Parse, I run into 26 errors related to sqlite. I've already created the bridging header as well as the entered the application id function within AppDelegate. Below are the various errors that I run into:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
  +[PFPushUtilities playAudioWithName:] in Parse(PFPushUtilities.o)
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
  +[PFPushUtilities playAudioWithName:] in Parse(PFPushUtilities.o)
  +[PFPushUtilities playVibrate] in Parse(PFPushUtilities.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in 
   Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in  Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
   -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
  ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
    -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_clear_bindings", referenced from:
  ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
  -[PFDateFormatter dealloc] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  ___30-[PFSQLiteDatabase closeAsync]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult dataForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult dataForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
  ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult doubleForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult intForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
  ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult longForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult stringForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult objectForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnIndexIsNull:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
  -[PFSQLiteDatabase _errorWithErrorCode:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
   -[PFDateFormatter dealloc] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  -[PFSQLiteStatement close] in Parse(PFSQLiteStatement.o)
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
  -[PFDateFormatter init] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  ___29-[PFSQLiteDatabase openAsync]_block_invoke in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
  -[PFDateFormatter init] in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
  ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  -[PFSQLiteStatement reset] in Parse(PFSQLiteStatement.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
  ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)
  -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult step] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Go to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" settings for your app and make sure that you add `libsqlite` library and `AudioToolbox` framework to your project.

Comment: Having this same issue.  And yes libsqlite and audio toolbox framework was added.  this started happing once I upgraded my project from swift 1.2 to 2.x